# Need to check whether the given time stamp is less than 30 minutes or not using groovy

Tags: groovy

I am getting the time stamp in the format of (dd.mm.yyyy:hh24:mi:ss)(02.03.2022:00:04:14)

i need to check whether the obtained value is 30 minutes less than the current time using groovy

can someone please help me in solving this problem.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'd do:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

String ts = "05.03.2022:03:36:00"

boolean isWithinTheLast( Date timestamp, int minutes ) {
   return (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp.time) <= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(30)
}

Date timestamp = Date.parse("dd.MM.yyyy:HH:mm:ss", ts)
println( new Date() )
println( timestamp )
println( isWithinTheLast( timestamp, 30) )
```